# Integration of Scheduling Software with SugarCRM

Tags: scheduling, sugarcrm

I am seeking an online scheduling solution for a client. The goal is to allow staff to schedule multiple appointments at multiple locations in association with multiple professionals.

One of the basic business requirements is it's ability to integrate with SugarCRM.  We are using Professional 6.X hosted by Sugar.

Where should I go to find a solution?
What are potential work around if I continue to be unable to find someone who has done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are TONS, or maybe 4, of schedulers/calendars designed to work with Sugar and they are available from Sugar Exchange and Sugar Forge. However, if you are working in Sugar 6.2 or better the calendar is dramatically improved and links into goto meeting and webex (two name two) very seamlessly.

In fact the calendar is SO improved it is easier to use in many ways than, oh let's say, outlook! it automatically logs your past and future planned meetings, call, events, tasks PLUS has a nifty shared calendar feature that lets you look at other peoples schedule to better plan meetings etc.

A single scheduler with many professionals to schedule could conceivably use these new and better tools to manage LARGE groups of professionals with a high degree of automation (thanks to Sugar's automated work-flows)